# I wanted to deploy my java 14 application to Heroku but I encountered some problems with java version

Tags: java, spring-boot, heroku, pipeline

I use bitbucket pipline to deploy my application to heroku. I added **system.properties** *java.runtime.version=14*, but it did not help me.
In heroku log: 
    Java app detected
    -----> Installing JDK 1.8... done
    -----> Installing Maven 3.6.2... done
    -----> Executing Maven
    .....
     Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default- 
   compile) on project ***: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 14 -> [Help 1]
**My bitbucket pipline looks:**

```
image: maven:3.6.1
clone:
 depth: full

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        name: Build and test
        image: maven:3
        caches: 
          - maven
        script:
          - mvn -B clean verify

    - step:
        name: Create artifact
        script:
          - tar czfv application.tgz pom.xml src/
        artifacts:
          - application.tgz
    - step:
        name: Deploy to production
        deployment: production
        script:
          - pipe: atlassian/heroku-deploy:0.1.1
            variables:
              HEROKU_API_KEY: $HEROKU_API_KEY
              HEROKU_APP_NAME: $HEROKU_APP_NAME
              ZIP_FILE: "application.tgz"
```

Comment: JDK 1.8 can't compile Java 14 but only until java 1.8/8.  Maybe you can configure Heroku to use another/newer version of the JDK (14)? (I'm not familiar with Heroku)

Answer (score 0):

Add to pom this lines:

`<properties>
        <java.version>14</java.version>
</properties>`

Check if you did with `system.properties` like this
Add `system.properties` to project folder with this line: 
`java.runtime.version=14`

App structure:

- YourApp
- system.properties
- src

  - main
- ...

Answer (score 0):

Main proplem was: application.tgz didn't contain system.properties 
I just added - tar czfv application.tgz pom.xml **system.properties** src/
here. 
How works fine. Thanks for your answers